# Idiomatic way in F# to establish adherence to an interface on type rather than instance level

Tags: f#

What's the most idiomatic way in F# to deal with the following. Suppose I have a property I want a type to satisfy that doesn't make sense on an instance level, but ideally I would like to have some pattern matching available against it?

To make this more concrete, I have defined an interface representing the concept of a ring (in the abstract algebra sense). Would I go for:

1.

```
// Misses a few required operations for now
type IRing1<'a when 'a: equality> =
    abstract member Zero: 'a with get
    abstract member Addition: ('a*'a -> 'a) with get
```

and let's assume I'm using it like this:

```
type Integer =
    | Int of System.Numerics.BigInteger
    static member Zero with get() = Int 0I
    static member (+) (Int a, Int b) = Int (a+b)

    static member AsRing
        with get() =
            { new IRing1<_> with
                member __.Zero = Integer.Zero
                member __.Addition = Integer.(+) }
```

which allows me to write things like:

```
let ring = Integer.AsRing
```

which then lets me to nicely use the unit tests I've written for verifying the properties of a ring. However, I can't pattern match on this.

2.

```
type IRing2<'a when 'a: equality> =
    abstract member Zero: 'a with get
    abstract member Addition: ('a*'a -> 'a) with get

type Integer =
    | Int of System.Numerics.BigInteger
    static member Zero with get() = Int 0I
    static member (+) (Int a, Int b) = Int (a+b)

    interface IRing2<Integer> with
        member __.Zero = Integer.Zero
        member __.Addition with get() = Integer.(+)
```

which now I can pattern match, but it also means that I can write nonsense such as

```
let ring = (Int 3) :> IRing2<_>
```

3.

I could use an additional level of indirection and basically define

```
type IConvertibleToRing<'a when 'a: equality>
    abstract member UnderlyingTypeAsRing : IRing3<'a> with get
```

and then basically construct the IRing3<_> in the same way as under #1.
This would let me write:

```
let ring = ((Int 3) :> IConvertibleToRing).UnderlyingTypeAsRing
```

which is verbose but at least what I'm writing doesn't read as nonsense anymore. However, next to the verbosity, the additional level of complexity gained doesn't really "feel" justifiable here.

4.

I haven't fully thought this one through yet, but I could just have an Integer type without implementing any interfaces and then a module named Integer, having let bound values for the Ring interfaces. I suppose I could then use reflection in a helper function that creates any IRing implementation for any type where there is also a module with the same name (but with a module suffix in it's compiled name) available? This would combine the benefits of #1 and #2 I guess, but I'm not sure whether it's possible and/or too contrived?

Just for background: Just for the heck of it, I'm trying to implement my own mini Computer Algebra System (like e.g. Mathematica or Maple) in F# and I figured that I would come across enough algebraic structures to start introducing interfaces such as IRing for unit testing as well as (potentially) later for dealing with general operations on such algebraic structures.

I realize part of what is or isn't possible here has more to do with restrictions on how things can be done in .NET rather than F#. If my intention is clear enough, I'd be curious to here in comments how other functional languages work around this kind of design questions.

Comment: Using `inline` it is possible to define something like a static interface which I think is what you want.  However, it is pretty ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question about how can you implement Rings in other functional languages, in Haskell you will typically define a [Type Class Ring](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.0.3/docs/Algebra-Ring.html) with all Ring operations.

In F# there are no Type Classes, however you can get closer using inline and overloading:

```
module Ring =
    type Zero = Zero with
        static member ($) (Zero, a:int) = 0
        static member ($) (Zero, a:bigint) = 0I
        // more overloads

    type Add = Add with
        static member ($) (Add, a:int   ) = fun (b:int   ) -> a + b
        static member ($) (Add, a:bigint) = fun (b:bigint) -> a + b
        // more overloads

    type Multiply = Multiply with
        static member ($) (Multiply, a:int   ) = fun (b:int   ) -> a * b
        static member ($) (Multiply, a:bigint) = fun (b:bigint) -> a * b
        // more overloads

    let inline zero() :'t = Zero $ Unchecked.defaultof<'t>
    let inline (<+>) (a:'t) (b:'t) :'t= (Add $ a) b 
    let inline (<*>) (a:'t) (b:'t) :'t= (Multiply $ a) b 

// Usage

open Ring

let z : int = zero()
let z': bigint = zero()

let s = 1 <+> 2
let s' = 1I <+> 2I

let m = 2 <*> 3
let m' = 2I <*> 3I

type MyCustomNumber = CN of int with
    static member ($) (Ring.Zero, a:MyCustomNumber) = CN 0
    static member ($) (Ring.Add, (CN a)) = fun (CN b) -> CN (a + b)
    static member ($) (Ring.Multiply, (CN a)) = fun (CN b) -> CN (a * b)

let z'' : MyCustomNumber = zero()

let s'' = CN 1 <+> CN 2
```

If you want to scale up with this approach you can have a look at [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) which already defines [Monoid](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/FsControl.Core/Monoid.fs) with Zero (Mempty) and Add (Mappend). You can submit a pull request for Ring.

Now to be practical if you are planning to use all this only with numbers why not use GenericNumbers in F#, `(+)` and `(*)` are already generic then you have `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` and `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne`.

Comment: I'll warrant that there might have been enough small typos in my code to make it unclear, I have corrected those now. That being said, it is definitely possible to have a discriminated union implement an interface, #2 is complies. I'll have to look to the rest of your answer in a bit more detail before deciding whether or not it is what I needed.

Comment: In the end FsControl (and the above) wasn't really what I was looking for for a few reasons, but since I didn't get any other answers, I'm market this as answered so it's closed